# Monitor not showing on full screen. It is showing the same display 4 times

Tags: display, virus, laptop

My laptop was working correctly two days earlier, then suddenly there was a core-dump and the system restarted.

When it started the display was not coming on correctly. It is now showing the same display four times on the screen. I tried to change the screen resolution and restored the system from the backup. However nothing worked.

Could it be a Virus? Is it a problem with the LCD display? Or could it be device drivers. I even tried to update display drivers, but the problem is resolved.

What should I try next?

Below are the screenshots of my problem:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like Microsoft has finally implemented multiple workspace feature available on Linux desktops. I bet they are about to patent it.

Comment: @VishaL: What is the make of your video card?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your video card is going bad.  This is a known problem on HP laptops of that model (or at least what I can guess is your model from the picture.)

[Google search for HP pavilion dv recall will gather a lot of info for you.](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1_____enUS420US421&aq=1&oq=HP%20dv9000&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=hp%20dv9000%20recall#sclient=psy&hl=en&rlz=1C1_____enUS420US421&source=hp&q=hp%20dv9000%20recall%20information&aq=1&aqi=p-p1g4&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=456959a837d449c5&pf=p&pdl=300)

Generally this is the video card over heating/burning up

Its related to nvidia cards specificly, and the way the heatsink is designed doesnt pass heat properly after a certain amount of time.

HP no longer warranties against this, they only extended it for a year.  It is no longer covered.  Best of luck.